# Convert function which putStrLn'd to return string

Tags: haskell, types

In a [standalone working script](https://github.com/leonstafford/pandoctest/blob/master/Main.hs), I have a function returning `IO ()` as such:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    response <- simpleHttp "https://leonstafford.github.io"

    let body = decodeUtf8 ( response )
    let bodyAsString = unpack ( body )

    putStrLn $ htmlToPlainText bodyAsString
```

I'm now trying to utilise same function in [this existing script](https://github.com/leonstafford/cli-rss-reader/blob/feature/pandoc-render-article/Main.hs), but struggling with the common `Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’`:

```
renderPage :: String -> String
renderPage url = do
    response <- simpleHttp url

    let body = decodeUtf8 ( response )
        bodyAsString = unpack ( body )
        articleAsPlainText = htmlToPlainText bodyAsString
    return articleAsPlainText
```

I have been fiddling with it off and on for about a week and hope I've been able to define the issue enough in the title, so as it may not be yet another `can't match expected types` post, though am pretty sure it is just that.

Comment: `renderPage :: String -> IO String`

Comment: no such luck `Expected type: String Actual type: IO String`

Comment: You removed the most important part of the error message: The file name / line number. Where does the new error occur?

Comment: ah, I see`Main.hs:222:29 linesOfText = lines pageOutput `  Would you like to change comment to answer so I may accept?

Comment: That probably means you wrote `let pageOutput = renderPage url` instead of `pageOutput <- renderPage url`.

Comment: I've tried it in a few places over the past week, but that func dec should keep me moving on, thanks! btw, the `vty <- ask ` line within `do` seems to prevent me from placing the `pageOutput <- renderPage url`, but I'll continue digging that on my own or place another question when I get stuck

Comment: `ask` sounds like you're in some kind of `ReaderT` environment. It's possible `pageOutput <- liftIO (renderPage url)` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The nice thing about Haskell is that you can do that step by step, mostly without fearing that you get completely different behaviour. First of all, we move the content of `main` into a new function:

```
renderPage :: IO ()
renderPage = do
    response <- simpleHttp "https://leonstafford.github.io"

    let body = decodeUtf8 ( response )
    let bodyAsString = unpack ( body )

    putStrLn $ htmlToPlainText bodyAsString


main :: IO ()
main = renderPage
```

Next, we add the `url` as argument:

```
renderPage :: String -> IO ()
renderPage url = do
    response <- simpleHttp url

    let body = decodeUtf8 ( response )
    let bodyAsString = unpack ( body )

    putStrLn $ htmlToPlainText bodyAsString

main :: IO ()
main = renderPage "https://leonstafford.github.io"
```

And last, but not least, we move `putStrLn` into `main` and use `return` in `renderPage`:

```
renderPage :: String -> IO String
renderPage url = do
    response <- simpleHttp url

    let body = decodeUtf8 ( response )
    let bodyAsString = unpack ( body )

    return $ htmlToPlainText bodyAsString

main :: IO ()
main = renderPage "https://leonstafford.github.io" >>= putStrLn
```

Those steps (move into new function, add arguments, move functionality out) were pretty small. So when you encounter a problem like this, don't be afraid to do some inbetween steps.

Note that `IO` always stays with `renderPage`, since `simpleHttp` uses `IO`. There is no way to get rid of `IO` once you have it somewhere in a function. But the functionality of `renderPage` can be re-used, since

```
renderPage :: String -> IO String
renderPage = fmap (htmlToPlainText . unpack . decodeUtf8) . simpleHttp
```

and therefore:

```
utf8ToPlainText :: ByteString -> String
utf8ToPlainText = htmlToPlainText . unpack . decodeUtf8

renderPage :: String -> IO String
renderPage = fmap utf8ToPlainText . simpleHttp
```

Comment: Sincere thanks for the answer/comments. It's both daunting and fun to take on Haskell as a n00b. I didn't have the confidence to write this question a week ago.

Comment: @LeonStafford: GIT GUD! Err, I mean, you're welcome. There's usually no harm in asking a question, as long as it's complete. By the way, `ask` has usually the type `Monad m => ReaderT r m r`, so you need to transform `ReaderT r IO a` back to `IO a`. That's usually done with `runReaderT`. But feel free to ask another question.